# Distributing Haskell on a cluster

Tags: haskell, closures, distributed

I have a piece of code that process files,

```
processFiles ::  [FilePath] -> (FilePath -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

This function spawns an async process that execute an IO action. This IO action must be submitted to a cluster through a job scheduling system (e.g Slurm).

Because I must use the job scheduling system, it's not possible to use cloudHaskell to distribute the closure. Instead the program writes a new *Main.hs* containing the desired computations, that is copy to the cluster node together with all the modules that main depends on and then it is executed remotely with "runhaskell Main.hs [opts]". Then the async process should ask periodically to the job scheduling system (using *threadDelay*) if the job is done.

Is there a way to avoid creating a new Main? Can I serialize the IO action and execute it somehow in the node?

Comment: Andrew Cowie and Ozgun Ataman suggested me to compile the program and ship it to the nodes, since the compiled binary is self-contained and easy to rsync. One example of this is hadron[1]-based Hadoop MapReduce programs to cluster nodes at work, developed by Ozgun Ataman.








[1] https://github.com/soostone/hadron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. There is a magical library called [`packman`](https://github.com/jberthold/packman). It allows you to turn any haskell thing into data (as long as it does not have `IORef`s or related things in them.) Here the things you would need:

```
trySerialize :: a -> IO (Serialized a)
deserialize :: Serialized a -> IO a
instance Typeable a => Binary (Serialized a)
```

Yep, those are the exact types. You can package up your `IO` actions using `trySerialize`, use `Binary` to transfer it to wherever, and then `deserialize` to get the IO action out, ready for use.

Caveats for `packman` is that:

- It stores things as thunks. This is probably what you want, so that the node can do the evaluating.

  - That said, if your thunk is huge, the `Binary` will probably be huge. Evaluating the thunk can fix this.
  - Like I said, mutable references are a no-no. One thing to watch out is them being *inside thunks* without you knowing it.

Other than that, this seems like what you want!